# setState in useEffect with that state as dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have A parent component with a child modal component. the parent component has a blank state variable passed down to child. the parent component also has a div that needs editorState initialized on render to work properly. My child component has a button that sets stateForDiv with some data to render in parent components div. I need parent component to setEditorState when child updates stateForDiv. Naturally I tried to use useEffect with stateForDiv as dependency. Well when the useEffect runs it creates and infinite loop when I run setEditorState. How can I set EditorState every time the stateForDiv changes without creating an infinite loop?

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {convertFromRaw, EditorState } from 'draft-js';
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent';


const ParentComponent = () => {

const [ editorState, setEditorState ] = useState(() => { return EditorState.createEmpty()}) // this must be initialized once on render
const [ stateForDiv, setStateForDiv ] = useState() // this state is passed down to child component, when the child component updates this state, we need to setEditorState.. this is my problem, infinite loop in useEffect when using stateForDiv as dependency


useEffect(() => {
if(stateForDiv) {
        setEditorState(EditorState.createWithContent(
          convertFromRaw(stateForDiv)));
  } else {
    console.log("false")
  }

}, [stateForDiv])

return (

<div currentContent={editorState} onChange={setEditorState} >

</div>

<div>
  <Modal>
    <ChildComponent setStateForDiv={setStateForDiv}
  </Modal>
 </div>
```

Child component that is setting state for stateForDiv

```
const ChildComponent = ({setStateForDiv}) => {


return (

<div>
  <button onClick={() => {setStateForDiv("<p>hi there</p>")} } ></button>
 </div>

)
}
```

Comment: i don't see any reason this code would cause an infinite loop. in fact, in this example your effect will only run twice: once on initial mount and again the first time the button is clicked.

Comment: I left out an onChange I just added it, the onChange is causing issue not sure how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

First point, `const [ stateForDiv, setStateForDiv ] = useState()` this statement is not required. Beacause you just want `<ChildComponent />` component which  onClick event to control `<div currentContent={editorState} >` component display. **You can** `<ChildComponent onClick={setEditorState(EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromRaw("<p>hi there</p>")));}/>`.

In addition, why your useEffect infinite loop.As your useEffect dependence is wrong.So you should take care how to use dependence.